# What is "__KEEPMAKEFILEO__E.o"?

Tags: linux, makefile, kernel

I read [Linux kernel ver.0.01 Makefile.](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/0.10/source/Makefile)
And I found a weird statement.

```
tools/system:   __KEEPMAKEFILEO__E.o __KEEPMAKEFILEO__F.o \
        $(ARCHIVES) $(LIBS)
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) boot/head.o init/main.o \
    $(ARCHIVES) \
    $(LIBS) \
    -o tools/system > System.map
```

what are __KEEPMAKEFILEO__E.o and __KEEPMAKEFILEO__F.o?

I googled it first, using keywords like "KEEPMAKEFILEO" and "KEEPMAKE".
But I couldn't find the definition of them. even in Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

For whom reached here because of the same issue, it's just a [Bootlin](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source)'s bug.
It's not a Linux or GNU make syntax. See [the right linux 0.01 code](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/Historic/).